# how to pass variables to method

Tags: python, class, oop

I want to pass variables to the method. which of the following is better? (x and y are constants)

```
class Class(Parent):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.d = self.function()
    def function(self):
        return self.x + self.y
```

or:

```
class Class(Parent):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.d = self.function(self.x,self.y)
    def function(self, x, y):
        return x + y
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'd argue the second one is better with regards to function purity, though this is a principle of Functional Programming rather than Object Oriented Programming. The only thing I'd wonder then is why you'd even make it a member method at all, instead of a stand-alone function.

Answer (score 1):

It depends. If `x` and `y` are constants and don't change, why would you want to pass them at all? Your `function` method can act like a helper function.

I don't know much more about your class and what do you want to do, but define those `x` and `y` as a "class variable". No need to save them in every single instances of class `Class`.

```
class Class(Parent):
    x = 'something'
    y = 'something_else'

    def __init__(self, var):
        super().__init__()
        self.d = self.function(var)

    def function(self, var):
        return Class.x + Class.y + var
```

Here I passed only `var` which is specific to different instances and used constant `x` and `y`.

If you don't use the instance (I mean `self`), omit it and just use a "staticmethod" instead to act like e helper function.